# State machines and map transitions

Tags: c++, tilemap, state, fsm

I've implemented a [basic] FSM in my game and it currently does its job very well. Recently I have come across a "problem" that I need to show a "Loading map. Please wait..." screen for as long the map is being loaded asynchronously. How do people usually do this? Is it considered a State?

For instance, these are the current states (in order):
IntroState (splash) -> LoadingState (loads textures, sounds...) -> PlayingState (optionally goes to PausedState)

The above LoadingState shows some kind of a progress bar while the assets are being loaded in another thread. Another information that might be important is that states operate the machine, for example, when the LoadingState finishes loading all the assets, it tells the machine to go to the playing state. The PlayingState has a Map object. For reference, see here: https://github.com/YvesHenri/Chico/tree/master/Game/Includes/Core/Engine/State

My current approach (which is not yet commited to github) is to make the Map object a "LoadingObservable" and the PlayingState a "LoadingListener" (observer pattern), so that inside the load call it will notify all of its listeners and theyre responsible of telling the FSM to go to the next or to go back to the previous state in the queue. Is this how people usually do that? Are there any easier/better ways to do that?

If this sounds a bit confusing please feel free to ask. Also, I'm always open for criticisms, if you have any, on my code.